# Inferring functions with different signatures in a union type

Tags: typescript, union-types

I've been attempting to type a function that takes a callback.

Said callback has a couple different but completely incompatible signatures. None of the callback signatures take the same type of argument in the same spot.

My problem is, I can't figure out how to (or even if I can) get the callback to infer in all cases.

This is about as minimal as I can make it:

```js
type A = (x: string) => void;
type B = (y: number, x: string) => void;

const c = (fn: A | B) => {};

c((x) => { console.log(x); });        // implicit any
c(((x) => { console.log(x); }) as A); // infers
c((y, x) => { console.log(y, x); });  // infers
```

I'm confused as to why the last case will infer, but the first case won't.

As I've been working on this, I've always had the problem that a function with *fewer* arguments won't infer, but the function with *more* arguments will.

My one working theory is that it has something to do with the fact that a callback of type `B` can validly only have one parameter:

```js
const a: A = (z) => z; // z: string
const b: B = (z) => z; // z: number
```

I have this distinct impression I'm missing something key here.

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. Are you aware that calling `fn` from the `c` function will be *"hard"* since the arguments the two unioned functions would resolve to `never` in this case since their signatures are not compatible? How will you be calling this function inside `c`? Maybe you have some other discriminator that will be used to differentiate the type of the function? Maybe this other discriminator should then be used for inference. Without an additional discriminator, it will be impossible at runtime to know if the function passed to `c` is `A` or `B`.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I wonder if the first case may not be inferred intentionally? In JavaScript, it is not an immediate error to call a function with fewer arguments than the function declares to take; those not passed will be `undefined`. Ex. `((a1,a2)=>{console.log(`a1: ${a1}, a2: ${a2}`);})(/*invoke with no args!*/);` will print `a1: undefined, a2: undefined`. TypeScript may be taking that into consideration.

Comment: @TobiasS. In the library I was attempting to type, the discrimination was based on `argument.length`. If I _were_ actually writing something like this, I'd add some internal type guards as well. But I'd probably just write a better setup that I wouldn't have difficulty typing.

Comment: @DavidFong That occurred to me too… but it doesn't make sense to call a function with a type that didn't mark its second argument as optional with just one argument. It may "work", but I might be missing something about why it's a good idea.